# How to run initialization script on starting a Rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, sh

I have a simple shell script (happy.sh) that I am currently running by hand (. ./happy.sh) every time I restart a rails server. It sets some environment variables that I need because of various APIs I'm using. However, I was wondering if there's some way of having rails run the script itself whenever I run "guard" or "rails s"

Thanks

Comment: try to add `RAILS_ENV=production ruby script/test.rb` in application.rb. and then restart a server and check

Comment: It's a shell script though

Comment: Nvm, I'll just try sh script/happy.sh

Comment: Where in the file should I add that?

Comment: RAILS_ENV=development sh "happy.sh"

Comment: can you write those environment variables in YAML file?

Answer (score 1):

If you use foreman, you can define all processes you needed started on application start into a Procfile. (including bbundle exec rails server -p $PORT)
By calling foreman start, all the process starts up.

More information can be gotten [here on this cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/281-foreman)

Answer (score 1):

Proper way of setting ENV variables is putting them in bash_proflle or bashrc depending of linux distro.

```
vi ~/.bash_proflle
```

And then add something like

```
export MY_RAILS_VAR=123
```

Then you don't need to run any ENV initialization scripts on rails start.